# Could someone explain this animated gif to me in mathematical terms?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I understand that the area of the two squares around the right triangle are the total area of the one that is the hypotenuse. Is this just a proof for the Pythagorean theorem or is there some other application for this?

[image: animated gif]

[link to animated gif](https://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/a3Yjz83_460sa.gif)

Comment: It's a demonstration of [Pythagoras' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Comment: I do not recognize a reference to any of the standard proofs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment notes it is no more and no less than a visual 'proof' of the Pythagorean theorem, $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2.  $$

The boxes associated with each side are cleverly constructed to be squares whose sides are, respectively, the lengths of the sides of the triangle. When boxes $a\cdot a$ and $b\cdot b$ are full, box $c\cdot c$ should be empty and v.v. Side $c$ is of course the hypotenuse.

The boxes are not perfectly flat (they have to accommodate the fluid) so there is probably some distortion of the exact dimensions to account for this.

It's also really fun to watch.

Edit: In response to two comments, it is evidently worth pointing out that the water device does not give a *proof* of the Pythagorean theorem, which is why I enclosed the word 'proof' in quotes. I would go further than the comments. The device is an educational toy designed to arouse interest or pique curiosity. It does not *prove*, *demonstrate*, or *verify*. The root of the word 'demonstration' occurs in QED. We would not want to associate the word with this exhibit. To verify is also to prove, in some sense, and this is also too strong. So I completely agree with the comments and hoped the quotation marks were enough. I even avoided 'visual proof,' which might have been construed as a non-verbal proof, hence possibly valid. The device offers an idea or suggestion. It is about as far as one can get from a formal proof while conveying an idea in an interesting way.

Comment: Yea, it is, I just never thought of it in that manner, which is why it intrigued me, but when you actually sit and explain it, it makes perfect sense. since the area of a square is length* width. Making a^2+b^2 = c^2..I would like to see something interesting done with the outer areas of those squares though, I can see that they also create triangles, although not right triangles.

Comment: No, although that is interesting as well, what I meant was the fact that the space between the outer squares also create triangles between them, notice how between the a and b square, there seems to be an isosceles triangle. and then another between b and c, so on. I wonder if there is some mathematical method to figure those out as well using some form of trigonometry.

Comment: @gandolf: Sure, if you are given the lengths of the sides (or their ratio) you can easily determine all the lengths and angles involved. To begin to think about it, try drawing lines that extend the sides of the triangle and draw the lines connecting the 'corners.'

Comment: How is this a proof? As far as I can tell, it's literally a demonstration, e.g. it literally verifies that a particular case of the Pythagorean theorem is true. I don't see how to go from here to a general proof.